# Adding Toolbar with images to items

Tags: ios, swift

I am adding a toolbar to the bottom of my viewcontroller page.

Then added a few bar items and removed the title and added image for each item in the attributes inspector.

However I noticed the images lost it colors and showing as a solid blue.

is there a way to fix this?
Please see the picture
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be the Toolbar tintColor doing the overwriting tricks,  try setting the tintcolor to clear?

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Also try setting the uiimage for the barButton to be UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal to prevent overwriting.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/imageWithRenderingMode:

Answer (score 0):

Swift:

```
UIToolbar.appearance().tintColor = .clearColor()
```